# ¿Como puedo mostrar un campo [NotMapped] desde una consulta API REST C#?

Tags: c#, api

tengo un modelo asi, donde oculto el campo de "Password":

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

lo oculto para evitar que se vea ese campo en las consultas que se hagan en los controllers, pero lo necesito solo al momento de hacer login y validar la contraseña.

solo que al momento de traerlo pues viene `null`. y al momento de enviarle esta consulta no trae nada, pues el campo esta null (o no mapeado):

```
var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == request.Email && u.Password == request.Password);
```

¿como puedo "desmapear" para este caso el campo "Password"?

Comment: Puedes tener un UserDTO donde solo pasas la información necesaria para el login, y otra clase para las interacciones de otros campos a nivel de BD.

Comment: pues la verdad no era la respuesta que necesitaba, pero termine resolviéndolo desde otro lado en mi proyecto. Gracias

Comment: Agrega la respuesta en la parte inferior de esta página, luego la marcas como aceptada, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo escenario o algún escenario muy similar. Saludos.

Comment: lo que pasa es que es muy especifico del proyecto que tengo, y habría que explicar muchas cosas, honestamente ni siquiera entendi como usar los DTOs pues el proyecto es muy diferente